# IVP of quasi-linear transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I need help second part of this problem:
Show that the solution $u$ of the quasi-linear PDE:

$u_y + a(u)u_x=0$

with initial condition $u(x,0)=h(x)$ is given implicitly by

$u=h(x-a(u)y)$

Show that the solution becomes singular for some positive $y$, unless $a(h(s))$ is a nondecreasing function of $s$

Here what I got the first part:

$u_y + a(u)u_x=0$

$u(x,0)=h(x)$

The initial curve $\Gamma : <x=s, y=0, z=h(s)>$ and the characteristic differential equations are $\frac{dx}{dt}=a(u), \frac{dy}{dt}=1, \frac{dz}{dt}=0$  .This leads to the parametric representation:

$x=a(u) + t$, $y=t$, $z=h(s)$. We solve and get $ s=x-a(u)y$ and solution of the initial value problem above is  $z=h(s)=h(x-a(u)y)$.

For second part, I am not sure what I did: The characteristic projection $C_s$ in the $xy$-plane passing through the point $(s,0)$ is the line

$ x=  s + a(u)y $ along which $u$ has the constant value $u=h(s)$ . Now two characteristics $C_{s_1}$ and $C_{s_2}$ intersect at a point $(x,y)$ with : $y=-\frac{s_2 - s_1}{a(h(s_2))-a(h(s_1))}$ (1). If $s_2\neq s_1$ and $a(h(s_2))\neq a(h(s_1))$, the function $u$ must take the distinct values $a(h(s_1))$ and $a(h(s_2))$ at $(x,y)$ and hence cannot be univalued. There always exist positive y of (1), unless $a(h(s))$ is a nondecreasing function  of s. For all other $a(h(s))$ the solution $u(x,y)$ becomes singular for some positive y.

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The proof is fine, since the statement "*the slope of the chords of $a\circ h$ is non-negative*" implies "*$a\circ h$ is non-decreasing*".

Now, what happens if $a\circ h$ is decreasing somewhere? Using the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) over $[s_1,s_2]$, we rewrite the intersection $(1)$ in OP as
$$
  y = -\frac{s_2-s_1}{a\circ h(s_2)-a\circ h(s_1)}
  = -\frac{1}{(a\circ h)'(s)}
$$
for some $s \in [s_1,s_2]$. Now, we obtain that the smallest $y>0$ at which characteristics intersect is given by
$$
y_b = \inf_{s\in\Bbb R} \left( -\frac{1}{(a\circ h)'(s)}\right) = \frac{-1}{\inf_{s\in \Bbb R} (a\circ h)'(s)}\, .
$$
This is the $y$ where a shock wave occurs (*breaking time*).

There are several other proofs than the previous geometric argument (cf. e.g. [(1)](http://www.acamedia.info/sciences/J_G/references/lax_1973.pdf)), which is based on the intersection of characteristics and the mean value theorem. Let us summarize a few methods:

1. **Dependence to initial data.** We differentiate the expression of characteristics $x = x_0 + a\circ h(x_0)\, y$ with respect to the initial abscissa $x_0$. This derivative vanishes at $y = -1/(a\circ h)'(x_0)$. The smallest such $y$ is the breaking time.
2. **Characteristic evolution of $u_x$.** We differentiate the PDE with respect to $x$, and we set $q=u_x$, $q' = q_y + a(u) q_x$. Hence, $q' + a'(u)\, q^2 = 0$, which solution is $q(y) = q_0/(1+q_0 k y)$, where $q_0 = h'(x_0)$ and $k = a'(u) = a'\circ h(x_0)$ is constant along the characteristics. Finally, $q$ blows up at $y = -1/(q_0 k) = -1/(a\circ h)'(x_0)$.
3. **Implicit function theorem.** The implicit equation $u = h(x-a(u) y)$ can be solved for $u$ as a differentiable function of $x$ and $y$ for $y$ small enough. Differentiating w.r.t. $x$, one has $u_x = q_0/(1+q_0 k y)$ with the same notations as above.

---

[(1)](http://www.acamedia.info/sciences/J_G/references/lax_1973.pdf) P.D. Lax, *Hyperbolic systems of conservation laws and the mathematical theory of shock waves*. SIAM, 1973. [doi:10.1137/1.9781611970562.ch1](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611970562.ch1)

Comment: Hello. Thank you and sorry, but I could not understand why is not $y_b = \inf_{s\in\Bbb R} \left( -\frac{1}{(a\circ h)'(s)}\right) = \frac{-1}{\sup_{s\in \Bbb R} (a\circ h)'(s)}\, .$. Many thanks.

Comment: @Na'omi The function $z\mapsto -1/z$ is increasing. Thus, $\inf (-1/z) = -1/\inf z$, where $z = (a\circ h)'(s)$ here.

Comment: Oh, my error, sorry. Many thanks.