# Quasi-linear pde $u_t + x u u_x = 0$, find shock time

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> Using the characteristics method, show that the Cauchy Problem for the
>   quasi-linear equation $$u_t + x u u_x = 0 \qquad u(0, x) = \phi(x) =
> \frac \pi 2 - \arctan(x)$$ has two shock times, $t^*_\pm $, one in the
>   future and one in the past. Determine $t^*_\pm $.

The characteristic curves are the solutions to the ODE system
$$ \dot t = 1 \qquad t(0) = 0$$
$$ \dot x = ux \qquad x(0) = x_0$$
$$ \dot u = 0 \qquad u(0) = \phi (x_0)$$
This yields the solutions $$x(t) = \exp(t\phi(x_0))+x_0+1$$
If this expression can be inverted into a function $x_0(t, x)$ then there is no shock, but if that is the case then $x(t)$ must be monotone as function of $x_0$. Thus, define $F_t(x) = \exp(t\phi(x))+x+1$ : I need to find the values of $t$ for which $F' >0$ for all $x$. This reduces to:
$$ \frac s {1+x^2} \exp\left (s\left (\frac \pi 2-\arctan(x)\right )\right ) < 1$$
At which point I am stuck. I cannot solve this inequality, but also I have the nagging feeling that I made a mistake somewhere earlier. Did I? And what are the shock times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As outlined by OP's self-answer,
$$
x(t) = x_0\exp(t\phi(x_0)) \, .
$$
Several methods can be used to find the shock times (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2445518/418542)). Here we examine the non-ambiguous dependence to the initial data. One observes that $\text d x/\text d x_0$ vanishes at $t=t_S$ such that
$$
t_S = \frac{-1}{x_0\phi'(x_0)} = x_0 + \frac{1}{x_0} \, .
$$
Thus, for positive times, the classical solution breaks at the *breaking time*
$$t^*_+ = \inf_{x_0>0} t_S = 2\, .$$
Similarly one gets $t^*_- = -2$ for negative times. This may be confirmed by a plot of the characteristics for several $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The exercise is supposed to be doable in 30 mins and with no notes or calculators. There might be an error in the statement.

Answer (score 3):

There is no error in the problem statement. Instead, I made a silly mistake in solving the ODE system for th echaracteristics, wich turn out to be
$$ x = x_0 \exp(t\phi) $$
From here on, the method I was trying to use, and that Harry49 explained in his answer.