# Why does burgers equation become discontinuous over time?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We have burgers equation $U_t+UU_x=0$.

We set the following initial conditions:

- $U(x,0) = 1 + 2/\pi \cdot \arctan(x) $

with clamped endpoints

- $U_\text{right endpoint}=0$
- $U_\text{left endpoint}=2$

Solving using the finite difference method with Forward Euler gives the following plot over time.
[image]

We have that the solution becomes 'square' and/or discontinuous over time. I am wondering what could explain this behavior. I believe it has to do with the top of the wave traveling faster than the bottom of the wave. However, this seems unsatisfactory.

Comment: Hi! I hope the pages 25-27 from Numerical Method for Conservation Laws, by R.J. LeVeque, will help you. The pages study the formation of shock at Burger's Equation. The shock occur when $U_0'(x)$ is negative at same point. It has relation with the inclination of carachteristics. Good studies.

Comment: @Na'omi Thanks. That is a very helpful resource. Here is the link for those that come along this post https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1470/c6f43c769572c4cfc94ffc9c5710484ff1e5.pdf

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2445518), where the computation of the *breaking time* is presented. Actually, it is easy to get an answer based on intuition. Indeed, the traveling speed of Burgers' equation $U_t+UU_x=0$ is  $U$. Since the data is zero on the right side, nothing moves there. However, the data on the left side is $U=2$, and it travels towards increasing $x$ at that speed. Therefore the left part is faster than the right part, and the waveform will break.