# Classical solution of $u_t + (u^4)_x = 0$ (characteristics)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

> Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an odd, continuous, increasing function on real line. Let us consider an equation:
> $$u_t + (u^4)_x = 0, \qquad (t,x) \in \mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}$$
> $$u(0,x) = g(x), \qquad x \in \mathbb{R} .$$
>
> a) Show that there exists classic solution on $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}$,
>
> b) Find $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} u(t,x)$ for fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
>
> c) Show that for every $t>0$ there exist $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}u(t,x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}u(t,x)$.

I was trying to do part a) by characteristics method, and here is what I managed to do:

Let $t=t(s)$, $x=x(s)$, $p(s)= \nabla u(x(s))$, $z(s) = u(x(s))$.

Let us consider a function:

$F(x, z, p) = p_1(s) + 4z^3(s)\cdot p_2(s)$.

We have $F_p(x,z,p) = [1, 4z^3(s)]$, so:

$t_s = 1$

$x_s = 4z^3(s)$

$z_s = [p_1, p_2] \cdot F_p = p_1 + p_2 \cdot 4z^3(s) = 0$.

And we have boundary conditions: $t(0) = 0$, $x(0) = \alpha$, $z(0) = g(\alpha)$.
After solving this system of ordinary differential equations, we obtain:

$t(s) = s$,

$z(s) = g(\alpha)$,

$x(s) = 4g^3(\alpha)\cdot s + \alpha$.

Now we want to express $(s, \alpha)$ in terms of $(t,x)$. And here comes the problem. Expressing $s$ in terms of $t$ is trivial, because we have $t(s) = s$. But when we want to express $\alpha$, then we have an equation for $x(s)$, where both $\alpha$ and $g(\alpha)$ appear. Can we obtain a formula for this solution? Or is it the end of the proof, because we know, that there exists $g^{-1}$ and it is possible to obtain a formula for alpha, although not directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Rewriting the PDE in quasi-linear form, $u_t + 4u^3 u_x = 0$, the solution obtained by the method of characteristics reads implicitly as
$$
u = g(x - 4 u^3 t)\, .
$$
The derivation in OP looks correct, since it leads to the same implicit formula.
Following one of the methods in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2445518/418542), we can show that the solution becomes singular unless $s\mapsto 4g(s)^3$ is a non-decreasing function of $s$. This property is true, as a consequence of the properties of $g$ and of the cubic polynomial function. Thus, the classical solution is defined for all $t\geq 0$.

b) Taking the limit as $t\to+\infty$ in the implicit formula yields $$\lim_{t\to+\infty} u(t,x) = 0\qquad\text{at}\qquad x =0 \, . $$
For other abscissas, I have no clue how to prove it, but I'd say $u\to 0$ too.

c) If $g$ is bounded, taking the limit in the implicit formula yields the result, and the values of $u$ at $x\to\pm\infty$ are the limits of $g$. If $g$ is unbounded, I've no clue how to prove the result.

Comment: I can see that the solution of a) is correct, but could you explain me how exactly taking the limit as $ t  \rightarrow  + \infty$ gives us the zero value of this limit?

Comment: @Joasia If $u> 0$ at $t\to+\infty$, then the right-hand side of the implicit equation equals $\lim g$ at $-\infty$, which is negative. This contradicts $u>0$. And similarly for $u<0$.