# solving $u^{2}u_{x} + u_{y}= 0$ and determine whether gradient catastrophe develops

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the IVP: $u^2u_x + u_y = 0, u(x,0) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and have to determine whether a gradient catastrophe develops.

My attempt: I used the method of characteristic to solve this IVP, and at the end got $u(x,y) = h(x - (u(x,y)^2y)$, where $h(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. However, I'm stuck at determining whether a gradient catastrophe develops. Is there any general way to determine whether gradient catastrophe happens? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You correctly found : $u(x,y) = h(x - (u(x,y)^2y)$, where $h(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ . Thus :
$$u=\frac{1}{1+(x-u^2y)^2}$$
This is the solution on the form of implicit equation. 

$u(x,y)$ is always positive and never tends to infinity.

Comment: @JJacquelin But will gradient catastrophe develop? Does "never tends to infinity" means there is no gradient catastrophe?

Comment: Hint: follow the steps in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2445518/418542)